# Should different disciplines of the same art have their own tag, or share tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Some martial arts have different disciplines that can be radically different arts, based on their regional and instructional origin.  Should these have separate tags?

Example: Shidokan can refer to Shorin-Ryu Shidokan (Okinawan in origin) or the World Karatedo Association Shidokan (Japanese in origin), which are totally different arts.

Answer (score 6):

This a hard one because some styles tend not to be well represented in various parts of the world (i.e. Renshinkan) even thought they might be well know in their country of origin. Personally I would be inclined to list both the parent style (i.e. `[shorinji-ryu]`) plus the name of the style itself so that the audience of people that would be interested in the question is expanded a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worthwhile to separate the different systems within a categorical martial art.

Chinese martial arts alone has hundreds of different systems that colloquially fall under the "kung fu" umbrella. There is some overlap and commonalities, but different styles often have distinctive movements that are unlike other styles.

I don't think it would be a huge disservice to the lesser known or smaller groups of a specific discipline otherwise all their questions would just end up being closed as "too localized." That would be too exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rob, we should probably have tags for the top level IE: Shidokan,  and for the more specific ones.