# Should we use tag for federations?

Tags: discussion, tags

Take Karate, there are styles like shotokan where exist more that one world federation. Should we use a tag for each federation (of course, when the question requires it; for example a question about the rules for federation X of Karate shotokan should be tagged [Karate] [shotokan] [X] [rules])?

Comment: Related question: [Should different disciplines of the same art have their own tag or share tags?](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/22/should-different-disciplines-of-the-same-art-have-their-own-tag-or-share-tags/)

Answer (score 1):

seems like a good idea to me!

i know in judo in canada there is just judo canada, and each province has an organization under it. But in the states, they have 2 (maybe 3) governing organizations and differentiating between them could be important

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to tag federations. If different disciplines in a martial art (there is a related [meta question](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/should-different-disciplines-of-the-same-art-have-their-own-tag-or-share-tags/)) are also tagged, I don't see why federations shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Only if it makes a difference to the likely answers. Otherwise we will end up with lots of unnecessary tagging.

So this also means that if the OP has used a federation specific tag but the accepted answer is not federation specific then the federation tag needs to be removed from the question.